# How to fix name 'fieldname' is not defined in django admin.py

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on a django app where I have a members model and another model called reviews.

My `members` model

```
class Members(models.Model):
  TITLES = (('chairman', 'Chairman'), ('secretary', 'Secretary'),)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TITLES, default='secretary')
  active = BooleanField(default=False)
```

My `reviews` model

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
  chairman = models.ForeignKey(Members, related_name='chairs', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  secretary = models.ForeignKey(Members, related_name='secretaries', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  review = models.TextField()
```

There could be several chairmen and secretaries but in the foreign key drop down, on the Reviews model, I would like to only display the ones who are active (i.e have the active field set to True). I have tried to achieve that by having the following in my `admin.py`...

```
class ReviewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  ...
  def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "chairman":
      kwargs["queryset"] = Members.objects.filter(title=='chairman', active==True)
    elif db_field.name = "secretary":
      kwargs["queryset"] = Members.objects.filter(title=='secretary', active==True)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Reviews, ReviewsAdmin)
```

I'm getting the error, `name 'title' is not defined` around where I'm doing the filter. What is wrong here?

Comment: Try to use on `=` instead of `==` as you are trying to compare `title` not defined variable and a string. Like `Members.objects.filter(title='secretary')`

Comment: Awesome. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only '=' inside the query.

```
if db_field.name == "chairman":
    kwargs["queryset"] = Members.objects.filter(title='chairman', active=True)
elif db_field.name = "secretary":
    kwargs["queryset"] = Members.objects.filter(title='secretary', active=True)
```